# Cannot install JEWEL in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I am trying to install [JEWEL](https://jewel.hepforge.org/gettingstarted.html) on UBUNTU 20.04. As mentioned in the documentation, it has a dependency on [LHAPDF](https://lhapdf.hepforge.org/). I have succesfully installed LHAPDF and it showed me a message like:

```
Libraries are installed in /usr/local/
```

But when I tried to install JEWEL, it showed an error:

```
Cannot find -lLHAPDF
```

I visited this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary), but could not figure out what to do, as I am not a Linux expert. I used:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

and copy pasted the `libLHAPDF.so` file from `/usr/local/lib` to `/usr/lib/`.
After that, I tried to run the `make` command again, but this time it showed a differnt error:

```
$ make
gfortran -o jewel-2.2.0-vac -L/usr/local jewel-2.2.0.o medium-vac.o pythia6425mod.o meix.o -lLHAPDF
/usr/bin/ld: pythia6425mod.o: in function `pypdfu_':
/home/aritra/Project/jewel-2.2.0/pythia6425mod.f:39228: undefined reference to `structa_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:10: jewel-2.2.0-vac] Error 1
```

Can any expert please help me install this?

Comment: Extraordinary well asked question: tagged, researched (incl. links), tried by examples (input + output), almost perfectly formatted  I will love to help with link-formatting and finding an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use packages from Ubuntu repositories.
The 18.04 LTS have LHPADF [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/lhapdf).
We can download them to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lhapdf/liblhapdf0v5_5.9.1-6_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lhapdf/liblhapdf-dev_5.9.1-6_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./liblhapdf0v5_5.9.1-6_amd64.deb ./liblhapdf-dev_5.9.1-6_amd64.deb
```

and then compile JEWEL:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran build-essential

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://jewel.hepforge.org/downloads/?f=jewel-2.2.0.tar.gz -O jewel-2.2.0.tar.gz
tar xvzf jewel-2.2.0.tar.gz
cd jewel-2.2.0/
make
```

to  use it by `./jewel-2.2.0-vac` or `./jewel-2.2.0-simple`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by a typo in fortran continuation. Edit file pythia6425mod.f:
on line 39228 there should be & on col 6 and GLU) on col 9-12 to look like this:

```
39227|           CALL STRUCTA(XX,QQ,MASS,UPV,DNV,USEA,DSEA,STR,CHM,BOT,TOP,
39228|     &  GLU)
```

Hope this helps